# MVC DropDownListFor gets disabled after the first selection and post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have an old ASPNET MVC application designed using Kendo(v4.0.30319). In the view I am using DropDownListFor  to populate a list of items. The way the webpage works is after selecting an item from dropdown, there will be an ajax call to load data into grid.

My problem is when the page gets loaded for first time, dropdown is populated and I am able to select the item and load the grid. But, once it's loaded the dropdown is inactive/disabled and I am not able to select any other item.

[Here is the snap of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQmUq.png)

Here is the code block from my view:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.company_id, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.CompanyList, "company_id", "company_name"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlCompany" })
            </div>
```

The script block is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlCompany').change(function () {
        $("#CompanyConnectorPropertyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read({ "companyConnectorID": 0 });
        $('#dvGrid').hide();
        $('#dvMessage').html('');
        if ($('#ddlCompany').val()) {
            BindConnectorDropdown();
        }
        else {
            $('#dvGrid').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#ddlConnector').change(function () {
        $('#dvMessage').html('');
        if ($('#ddlConnector').val() && $('#ddlConnector').val() > 0) {
            $("#CompanyConnectorPropertyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read({ "companyConnectorID": $('#ddlConnector').val() });
            $('#dvGrid').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#dvGrid').hide();
        }
    });

    var connectorID = getParameterByName('cid');
    if (connectorID) {
        $("#ddlConnector").val(connectorID);
        $('#ddlConnector').trigger('change');
    }        
});
```

There is nowhere it's mentioned to disable the dropdown.
I want the dropdown to be active so that I can select a diffrent item , bind it and get data. Any help to solve the problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which dropdown are you referring to?  or both?

Comment: maybe add `$('#ddlConnector').dropdown();` and/or `$('#ddlCompany').dropdown();`

Comment: Both of them become inactive after loading the grid data.

Comment: Have you added what I suggested?

Comment: Yes. I added it after the dropdown change function is called, but no result.